# Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugin-push

I'm creating a Cordova app and have the following plugins:

```
com.googlemaps.ios 3.8.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-play-services-version-adapter 1.0.2 "Cordova/Ionic Google Play Services Versions Incompatibility Adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 2.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.1 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 4.0.0 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.7.1 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 3.0.1 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.3 "Media"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.4 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-vibration 3.1.1 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-support-google-services 1.3.2 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 5.0.4 "Launch Navigator"
```

All compiles fine and the app runs. But when adding:

`phonegap-plugin-push 2.3.0 "PushPlugin"`

I then get this error:

```
'Cordova Play Services Version Adapter' has detected an error. The following dependencies of 'Google Play Services' are not compatible:
You have an incompatibility of versions with the following dependencies of 'Google Play Services':
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    - 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
    - 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.+'

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
  1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
  
  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
  15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.
  
  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@16.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@16.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.0.+
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@15.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@15.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@17.0.0
```

I cannot figure this one out. Been at it for 10 hours before asking. I simply cannot figure this out. I tried editing the `project.properties` file and changing the version from 16.0.0 to 15.0.0 and many other things but nothing is working.

As soon as I remove `phonegap-plugin-push` everything works again.

I'm not too experienced with this so maybe I am doing something completely wrong. If anyone has any idea that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you get any solution ?